# OpenSSL Encryption AES 128bit CBC

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, aes

When I run this program, AES_cbc_encrypt produces a different cipher during every loop.  Is there a way to reset the state, so that the same cipher is produced during every loop?

```
void main() 
{
int i;
unsigned char iv[]  = "\x09\x08\x07\x06\x05\x04\x03\x02\x01\x00\xA2\xB2\xC2\xD2\xE2\xF2";
unsigned char plaintxt[] = "\x25\x50\x44\x46\x2d\x31\x2e\x35\x0a\x25\xd0\xd4\xc5\xd8\x0a\x34";
unsigned char ciphertext[] = "\xd0\x6b\xf9\xd0\xda\xb8\xe8\xef\x88\x06\x60\xd2\xaf\x65\xaa\x82";
unsigned char cipher[128];
char key[] = "\x95\xfa\x20\x30\xe7\x3e\xd3\xf8\xda\x76\x1b\x4e\xb8\x05\xdf\xd7";


for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {

    AES_KEY aeskeyEnc;
    AES_set_encrypt_key(key, 128, &aeskeyEnc);
    AES_cbc_encrypt(plaintxt, cipher, 33, &aeskeyEnc, iv, AES_ENCRYPT);


    for (i = 0; i < KEYSIZE; i++) {     
        printf("%.2x", (unsigned char)cipher[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}   
}
```

Comment: This is a feature of Cipher Block Chaining and is important for security.  Electronic Codebook would produce the same results each time, but you have to have a really, really good reason for this as it substantially weakens encryption. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @SteveFriedl The IV is fixed. OpenSSL keeps state.

Comment: my guess, there is a bufferoverflow?

Comment: @SteveFriedl  My plaintext is exactly one block(128bit) long, so even CBC should produce the same ciphertext right?

Comment: Did you check the default padding? you should say no padding in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nevermind, it seems it's because for some weird reason AES_cbc_encrypt function modifies the IV.

```
for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {

    AES_KEY aeskeyEnc;
    unsigned char iv[]  = "\x09\x08\x07\x06\x05\x04\x03\x02\x01\x00\xA2\xB2\xC2\xD2\xE2\xF2";
    AES_set_encrypt_key(key, 128, &aeskeyEnc);
    AES_cbc_encrypt(plaintxt, cipher, 33, &aeskeyEnc, iv, AES_ENCRYPT);


    for (i = 0; i < KEYSIZE; i++) {     
        printf("%.2x", (unsigned char)cipher[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```